# Django: data send from Ajax to Python is emptied

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to get a string data that is send from Ajax to Python. However, as I log the code, the data isn't sent. It's empty. Could you tell me why?

*p.s. the purpose of the code is to get the name of the submit button to validate in views.py*

**javascript**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(".submit-btn").click(function(){
  var button_pressed = JSON.stringify($(this).attr('name'));
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'add_test' %}",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'button_pressed' : button_pressed, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
  })
});
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def add_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test_name = request.POST.get('test_name')
        test_type = request.POST.get('test_type')
        test_date = request.POST.get('test_date')
        test_obj = Test(test_name = test_name, test_type = test_type, test_date = test_date)
        test_obj.save()
        button_pressed = request.POST.get('button_pressed')
        #button_pressed = json.loads(button_pressed)        
        print button_pressed ,"+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/test-management/test/')
```

**test_list.html**

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'add_test' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <h2>Add Test</h2>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <p>Name :</p>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test_name" name="test_name" placeholder="Test Name...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <p>Type :</p>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test_type" name="test_type" placeholder="Test Type...">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <p>Date :</p>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="test_date" name="test_date" placeholder="Test Date...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-wd btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-wd btn-lg submit-btn" name="add_new">Add & New</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" name="add">Add</button>
                        </div>
</form>
```

I am new to Django, so sorry if the question is silly. Thank for helping!

Comment: your `button_passed` not passed by ajax?

Comment: @sueling yes, value of `button_passed` isn't passed.

Comment: can you make a console.log of this?
 var button_pressed = JSON.stringify($(this).attr('name'));

Comment: please check your script work like @JorgePeris said

Comment: @JorgePeris i console.log it and get the value. it works to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type `submit` button:-

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" name="add">Add</button>`

to

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" name="add">Add</button>`

Comment: I finally decide to change my logic and follow your suggestion. I changed the button type from `'submit'` to `'button'`.

Comment: when you performing `click` event  on a button, type `button` is perfect choice. In case of `submit` it perform on  your `form submit`,  not  in your ajax. If type `submit` is very necessary then go for `preventDefault` option as mention in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your form is sended with your submit button. It send your `form` data, not ajax data.

Just send ajax with other button or add `preventDefault()`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(".submit-btn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var button_pressed = JSON.stringify($(this).attr('name'));
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'add_test' %}",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'button_pressed' : button_pressed, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
  })
});
</script>
```

Also, you have to change your view if you want to receive your form data

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that we can't get the name of the submit button if it's of type `'submit'`. So, I made the type to `'button'`. There are quite a few modification that I do to make the code work, but it all works fine now.

**javascript**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(".submit-btn").click(function(){
  var test_name = JSON.stringify($("#test_name").val());
  var test_type = JSON.stringify($("#test_type").val());
  var test_date = JSON.stringify($("#test_date").val());
  var button_pressed = JSON.stringify($(this).attr('name'));
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'add_test' %}",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'button_pressed' : button_pressed, 'test_name' : test_name, 'test_type' : test_type,
    'test_date' : test_date,'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
  })
  var button_pr = $(this).attr('name');
  if (button_pr == 'add_new'){
    $("#test_name").val("");
    $("#test_type").val("");
    $("#test_date").val("");
  } else {
    $(".cancel-btn").click();
  }
});
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def add_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test_name = json.loads(request.POST.get('test_name'))
        test_type = json.loads(request.POST.get('test_type'))
        test_date = json.loads(request.POST.get('test_date'))
        test_date = datetime.strptime(test_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        test_obj = Test(test_name = test_name, test_type = test_type, test_date = test_date)
        test_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/test-management/test/')
```

**test_list.html**

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'add_test' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <h2>Add Test</h2>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <p>Name :</p>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test_name" name="test_name" placeholder="Test Name...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <p>Type :</p>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test_type" name="test_type" placeholder="Test Type...">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <p>Date :</p>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="test_date" name="test_date" placeholder="Test Date...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-wd btn-lg cancel-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-wd btn-lg submit-btn" name="add_new">Add & New</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" name="add">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Basically, I write java script code to get value of form fields, send them to `'add_test'` as Ajax. To get name of the button I clicked, I cannot use button of type `'submit'`. Thank you